# What is the logic of a query when using like with and/or

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that contains subtitles ranging from subtitles_a to subtitles_z. I'm not sure why this query isn't working?

```
select * from subtitles
where field_name like '%subtitle_u%' or field_name like '%subtitle_v%'
```

This returns back everything in the range from subtitles_a to subtitles_z.

When I use the AND, I get values from subtitle_u to subtitle_v, shouldn't using an OR have given me these results instead?

```
select * from subtitles
where field_name like '%subtitle_u%' and field_name like '%subtitle_v%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Underscore means "a single wildcard character". I'd suggest this is affecting your results. Try doing;

```
select * from subtitles
where field_name like '%subtitle\_u%' escape '\'
or field_name like '%subtitle\_v%' escape '\'
```